# Render SSRS report in Silverlight app securely, via WebClient byte[] or alternative

Tags: silverlight, reporting-services, webclient

I'm trying to implement a SSRS reporting feature in a Silverlight 5 application, which is operating in browser mode.

*Attempt 1)*
The initial plan was to render the page using the URL technique on the Silverlight client

```
var path = item.Path; // Where item.Path is something like '/MyReportFolder/Report1'
var url= @"http://<MyServerAddress>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?{0}&rs:Command=Render";
var completeUrl = string.Format(url, path.Replace(@"/", "%2f").Replace(" ", "+"));
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(completeUrl), "_newWindow", "toolbar=0,menubar=0,resizeable=1,scrollbars=1");
```

The issue here is that permission to call this URL would be difficult to manage, and is not related to the basic security under which the Silverlight application operates.

*Attempt 2)*
Render the report on the IIS server (instead of on-the-client, on behalf of the user via a WCF call) via a similar Url call in a WebClient and download the byte[] output, then send the byte[] to the Silverlight client (as a response to the WCF call), and then render the content within the Silverlight app.

```
var path = itemPath;
var url = @"http://<MyServerAddress>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?{0}&rs:Command=Render";
var completeUrl = string.Format(url, path.Replace(@"/", "%2f").Replace(" ", "+"));

var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>();
var webClient = new WebClient();

webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (sender, args) => tcs.TrySetResult(args.Error != null ? args.Result : new byte[0]);
webClient.DownloadDataAsync( new Uri(completeUrl));
return tcs.Task;
```

Works fine also to render the report to a byte[], and the security is easily handled via the WCF service operation call. However, once the byte[] is received on the client, I'm not aware of how to show the result on the screen.  My preference would be to open a new browser window and render the content into it, however the System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window does not support this.

So my options are:

1. Render the result on the IIS server to a temporary file and send the URL (instead of the byte[]) to the Silverlight client, so a browser client can open the result. This is a bad result, as the outcome is very similar to *Attempt 1* as the Url is then available to third party receivers
2. Render the report as a TIFF byte[], however I'm not sure this will handle multipage reports, and it may not support PDF and XLS report content, as a TIFF would need to be displayed in a Silverlight Image Control, instead of the browser.
3. Some other fantastic alternative I've yet to consider...

Has anyone else attempted an enterprise SSRS feature in a Silverlight application and found  solutions to similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

There is a component - [PerpetuumSoft Viewers For SSRS](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/PerpetuumSoft-Viewers-for-SSRS.aspx) (it's our component I need to confesss)  which seamlessly integrates SSRS reports in Silverlight applications using a native XAML based viewer. So we obviously found the solution.